# How get a very high quality image of the plot

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I am using texstudio.

Q1: I want to convert the pdf output to high quality eps file. How to do that?

Q2: Is it possible to increase the quality of pdf output also, if I replace the 1st line of the code by \documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}

**Note that the convert option is not working for me. What to do? I want to get a very very high quality image of the plot.**

```
\documentclass[convert={density=3000,size=8000x8000,outext=.eps}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=.1pt},
        declare function={f(\x,\y)=2-0.5*pow(\x-1.25,2)-0.5*pow(\y-1,2);}]
        \begin{axis}[view={150}{45},colormap/blackwhite,axis lines=middle,%
            zmax=2.2,zmin=0,xmin=-0.2,xmax=2.4,ymin=-0.2,ymax=2,%
            xlabel=\Large$x$,ylabel=\Large$y$,zlabel=\Large$z$,
            xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,ztick=\empty]
            % Surface plot with mesh
            \addplot3[mesh,shader=interp,domain=0.6:2,domain y=0.5:1.9,opacity=0.99] 
            {f(x,y)};
            \draw[ultra thick, red] (0.6,0.5,{f(0.6,0.5)}) to[bend left=30] (2,0.5,{f(2,0.5)});
                    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Technically, pdf are usually in vectorial format, so it should already have "infinite quality" since fonts/curves are defined via a mathematical formula instead of pixels. So maybe the problem is that your tikz plot is not using enough samples from the beginning. Maybe try setting `samples` like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252970/how-to-increase-resolution-of-a-picture-in-tikz

Comment: How to convert the pdf output to high quality eps file using texstudio

Comment: texstudio is just the editor you used to write the source file it  is not directly involved in generating the pdf or converting it to postscript. (why do you need eps these days??) converting a vector plot from pdf to eps or the reverse is a lossless transformation usually done with a script such as pdf2ps or pdftops

Comment: (1) At 1600% zoom I cannot see any lost of quality in the PDF output. (2) Export an image to another format  will never increase the quality, may be the opposite, especially when the source is already a vectorial image.  (3) Since the lower cretaceous or so, "modern" engines (pdflatex, xelatex and lualatex) do not manage EPS directly, so this will force a nonsense pdf → eps → pdf  conversion, expecting  if you really want produce the fossil .dvi format  (that actually only known a few surviving dinosaurs and young people reading very outdated manuals).

Comment: (4) just guessing: You have a PDF viewer that cannot render very well vectorial images at some sizes,  but zooming it you will check no lines any line is pixelated, so it is not a problem of quality of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Just leave the MWE "as is". This is a zoom of the top left corner of the surface (the dark rectangle of the miniature) with the okular viewer. Simply you cannot improve the quality of this output in any way.

[image: mwe]

Comment: Thank you... When I use this Fig in a latex document to prepare a pdf file with text and figures, it is GOOD. But in pagemaker, the Fig, quality becomes very poor. That is why I want to produce a high quality png or eps.

Comment: Then is a problem of PageMaker that, afaik is now a very old program  and  is off-topic here. Said that, Imagemagick always rasterize your PDF, therefore  some like `convert -density 300  in.pdf -quality 100  out.pdf` not only increase absurdly the file size but also decrease the image quality **a lot**. Try to load the PDF with Inkscape to increase the 96 ppp for rasterization when  saved as PDF and EPS formats and when    exported as PNG, may some of them work well with pagemaker, but as said, whatever export pay taxes.